# Can I validate Azure credentials without generating Certificate for my machine?

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to validate client_id, client_secret (all the basic credentials required to make api calls to Azure). I suppose one way of doing it is to generate token with the given client_id, client_secret and etc.
Is this the correct way of doing it? If yes, what else do I need? Do I need to upload Certificate for my machine? If no, how can I do this?

```
def get_token(self, client_id, client_secret, endpoint_url, resource_url=None):
    if not resource_url:
        resource_url = 'https://management.core.windows.net/'
    payload = {
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials',
        'client_id': client_id,
        'client_secret': client_secret,
        'resource': resource_url,
    }
    try:
        response = requests.post(endpoint_url, data=payload).json()
        token = response.get('access_token')
        if token:
            return token
    except Exception as e:
        LOG.exception(e.message)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear for understanding your real scenario. However, per my experience, I think the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/#create-the-request) about how to create a request to to acquire the access token from Azure AD is helpful for you. If you can improve your description, I think I can reply more helpful details for you.

Comment: I'm not proposing this as a solution, just want to be sure you know about ADAL (https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python) from MS to do that for you. If you know it exists but don't want to use it for some reason, that's fine.

Comment: @PeterPan-MSFT I have edited my question.

Comment: @LaurentMazuel Yes I'm aware of that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is not an absoluted correct answer for your question without a scenario. Normally, there are two ways for authentication on Azure, which include using AAD & using management certificate, and be relate to Azure Resource Management (ARM) & Service Management (ASM).

For example, if you want to create an service on Azure, you can do the authentication with ARM via token which need `client_id` & `client_secret`, or also with ASM via management certificate which need a .cer file for server & a .pem file for client.

As references, you can follow the below documents to know them within Python.

1. For ARM, https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0rc4/resourcemanagement.html
2. For ASM, https://azure-sdk-for-python.readthedocs.io/en/v2.0.0rc4/servicemanagement.html

Meanwhile, you can know more details via search the key words (like `Azure Resource Management Authentication`, `ASM authenticate`, etc) on Search Engines or [MS Azure Search](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?q=), or via ADAL project for Python on GitHub as @LaurentMazuel said.

Hope it helps. If you want more help for some specified scenario like creating a VM or others, please feel free to let me know and improve your question in details.